# Transitive RPATH property in CMake

Tags: cmake

I am building a library that I bundle with a few tests and example programs. The project is able to honor the cmake property `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`, building a `.so` if it's on and building a `.a` file if it is off. The library depends on a few other dynamic libraries, which are supposed to be found using an environment variable, `LIBLOC` (their convention, not mine).

When I build the dynamic version of the library, I am able to set up the install rpath so that the libraries are found correctly. E.g.:

```
add_library(lib ${SRC})
set_target_properties(lib INSTALL_RPATH $LIBLOC)
install(TARGETS lib LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

And then in each test/example program's CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(test lib)
set_target_properties(test INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN/../lib)
install(TARGETS test RUNTIME bin)
```

When `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is on, the test program is happy:

```
$ lddtree bin/test
test => bin/test (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    liblib.so => /path/to/install/liblib.so
        libdep.so => /path/to/dependency/libdep.so
```

We can find everything because the rpath in test is `$ORIGIN/../lib`, which finds `liblib.so` and then the rpath in `liblib.so` is `$LIBLOC`, which is set in my environment to `/path/to/dependency`.

I would have expected that, when installing the static library, cmake would read the `INSTALL_RPATH` property from my library and put it in the test program so that the rpath in test would be `$ORIGIN/../lib;$LIBLOC`. Instead, `$LIBLOC` does not end up in any rpath.

My current solution is dissatisfying: I condition my `INSTALL_RPATH` on `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` in each example or test program, e.g.

```
if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set_target_properties(test INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib")
else ()
  set_target_properties(test INSTALL_RPATH "$LIBLOC")
endif ()
```

Now I have several targets, all of which have to be aware of their dependencies' dependencies. Plus a bunch of smelly if statements. Yuck!

Is there a nicer way in cmake to pass the install rpath "up" to the first ELF file produced when my libraries are compiled statically?

Comment: The syntax `$LIBLOC` does not access an environment variable in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

The `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` variable may be set *externally* and will apply to all targets for which `RPATH` is well defined (i.e. executables and shared libraries).

For libraries you author or vendor, you should install them into a consistent structure so that `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` may be set to `$LIBLOC` or `$ORIGIN/../lib` uniformly across all targets. For true dependencies, it is reasonable to expect the user to have them installed system-wide, have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or use the `find_dependency` macro in your CMake package config to locate the correct libraries.

Here's a snippet that might help you, if placed before any targets are created:

```
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH)
  # or perhaps it's meant to be $env{LIBLOC}?
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$<IF:$<BOOL:${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}>,$ORIGIN/../lib,$LIBLOC>")
endif ()
```